# Buying train ticket from Bucharest to Constanța online?

Tags: trains, tickets, online-resources, bookings, romania

I am going to Bucharest in the middle of September, and I want to goto Constanța by train. By using the Internet, I've found there should be quite a lot of train rides going there.

However, I am used to buying all my tickets beforehand online, to make sure it doesn't get sold out. I couldn't find a similar thing for this trip.

So I guess my question is twofold:

- Is there anyway to buy the ticket online?
- Does it even make sense? Or can you expect it will just be available when you are there?

Comment: tried seat61.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Man in Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/Romania.htm#Booking%20trains%20within%20Romania) says that tickets can be booked on the online website of CFR, the Romanian Railway company. [Here is the official CFR wesbsite](http://www.cfrcalatori.ro/). Quoting from The Man:

> #### How to book trains within Romania
>
> [...]
>
> You can book Romanian domestic train tickets online at www.cfrcalatori.ro, the Romanian Railways (CFR) website, including domestic sleeper trains.  It will only book the compulsory-reservation mainline trains, not local services, but it's easy enough to use and should have no problem with non-Romanian credit cards.